# How can I copy only the most recent file from each folder and subfolder while retaining directory structure?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I'm working with a directory with a structure as: account name → year → files.

Within each group of files by year and name there are usually one or more files that contain `"*Data Rec*"` in the file name.  I would only like to take the most recent file with that name for each group of files.  Right now I have the below code that works, but only returns one file even though there is a folder for 2012, 2013, and 2014 each containing at least one `"*Data Rec*"` file.  Also it doesn't retain the directory structure.  It only drops the file into the destination.  The file is from the 2014 folder so I would like my destination to contain the 2014 folder with the `"*Data Rec*"` file inside.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter "*Data Rec*" |
  Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1 |
  % { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination }
```

Eventually I would like to also be able to search for the most recent `"*Analysis*"` file if the selected folder doesn't contain a `"*Data Rec*"` file.

Comment: Personally I would use PS to get the desired source path and destination path and then execute RoboCopy or something to perform the actual file copy since it'll only overwrite files when they're updated, and it will maintain directory structure and all that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Is there a way to integrate the Get-ChildItem parameters with robocopy?  I can't find a way to use robocopy to take just the most recent file from each folder with that filter critera.

Comment: Crud, did I say RoboCopy? I mean [RichCopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx). A pet project from a Microsoft employee a few years ago that copies files. It's like RoboCopy but more awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use two `Get-ChildItem` statements, one to enumerate the folders, the other to enumerate the files in each folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem -File -Filter "*Data Rec*" |
    Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Copy-Item -Destination $destination
}
```

If you're not using PowerShell v3 or newer you need to replace the parameters `-Directory` and `-File` with `Where-Object` filters checking the objects' `PSIsContainer` property.

To preserve the folder structure you need to remove `$path` from the full path of the file to be copied and append that to the destination path.

```
{ Join-Path $destination ($_.FullName.Replace("$path\", '')) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not working with PowerShell v3 and I am having trouble replacing the -Directory and -File parameters.  I understand for -Directory I want to replace it with 'Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} ', but I'm not sure how to replace -File.

Comment: @Cole Just to be clear, by "replacing the parameters" I didn't mean to literally substitute them in-place, but to remove them and add a `Where-Object` filter to the pipeline. As for matching files, instead of matching things that are containers (i.e. directories) you simply need to match things that are *not* containers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of a necro post, but the solution posted above by Ansgar didn't quite work for me. I had to tweak it in order for it to work properly. Not really sure if I should be posting this as a new answer or as a comment to his answer, so if I'm doing this wrong, please let me know, and how to fix it!

Here's the code that I ended up using. It takes the newest file in each subdirectory, and copies it to the destination. It also creates the destination directory first, if it doesn't exist. I'm not sure how to make the script work with multiple lines, so it'll look kinda ugly - sorry! Finally, in the original example, the person was searching for a different term than I was (I searched "*bak") - just replace the search term with what is being searched for.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path\$_" -File -Filter "*bak" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Copy-Item -Force -Destination (New-Item -Force -Type Directory -Path (Join-Path $DestinationPath ($_.FullName.Replace("$Path\", ''))))}
```

In a perfect world, the script would not copy the file if it already existed. That's doable, by just removing the -Force, but if I do that, it spits out ugly error messages instead. Still, perhaps that's better than overwriting. Strange, though, that Copy-Item doesn't allow an option to explicitly not copy if the destination file name exists.